# ROC_CURVE- IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, roc

classification, when I input numpy arrays having test label and test probabilities, it throws the following error

```
dataset = read_csv('C:/.../dataset/KDDREAL.csv')
dataset = dataset.values
X = dataset[:, :-1]
Y = dataset[:, -1]

encoder = LabelEncoder().fit(Y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)


X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X , encoded_Y , test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

model_svm = svm.SVC()
model_svm.fit(X_train, Y_train) 
results_svm = model_svm.predict(X_test)

fpr2 = dict()
tpr2 = dict()
roc_auc2 = dict()
for i in range(num_classes):
    fpr2[i], tpr2[i], _ = roc_curve(Y_test , results_svm[:, i])
    roc_auc2[i] = auc(fpr2[i], tpr2[i])
    # Compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area
fpr2, tpr2, _ = roc_curve(y_test.ravel(), PGD20_X_test_trm.ravel())
roc_auc2 = auc(fpr2, tpr2)
```

```
fpr2[i], tpr2[i], _ = roc_curve(Y_test , results_svm[:, i])

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: have you checked the shape of Y_test and results_svm?

Comment: You just need to pass `results_svm`.

Comment: You just need to pass results_svm... i dont understand

Comment: the shape Y_test and results_svm are (210,) (210,) respectively

Answer (score 1):

For the line of code given below -

```
for i in range(num_classes):
       fpr2[i], tpr2[i], _ = roc_curve(Y_test , results_svm[:, i])
```

Try and replace it with -

```
for i in range(n_classes):
      fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(Y_test[:, i], results_svm[:, i])
```

In case you are copying this line please check for the indentation.

Comment: i did edit the codes as you said yet the same error